# YUV video displaying on CardboardView

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, google-cardboard

I'm trying to modify WebRTC Android http://webrtc.org/native-code/android/ to display video stream into Google CardboardView. In SurfaceViewRenderer.java and [GlRectDrawer.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/app/webrtc/java/android/org/webrtc/GlRectDrawer.java) Sources, they use these vertex and fragment shader:

```
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER_STRING =
    "varying vec2 interp_tc;\n"
  + "attribute vec4 in_pos;\n"
  + "attribute vec4 in_tc;\n"
  + "\n"
  + "uniform mat4 texMatrix;\n"
  + "\n"
  + "void main() {\n"
  + "    gl_Position = in_pos;\n"
  + "    interp_tc = (texMatrix * in_tc).xy;\n"
  + "}\n";


private static final String YUV_FRAGMENT_SHADER_STRING =
    "precision mediump float;\n"
  + "varying vec2 interp_tc;\n"
  + "\n"
  + "uniform sampler2D y_tex;\n"
  + "uniform sampler2D u_tex;\n"
  + "uniform sampler2D v_tex;\n"
  + "\n"
  + "void main() {\n"
  // CSC according to http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php
  + "  float y = texture2D(y_tex, interp_tc).r;\n"
  + "  float u = texture2D(u_tex, interp_tc).r - 0.5;\n"
  + "  float v = texture2D(v_tex, interp_tc).r - 0.5;\n"
  + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(y + 1.403 * v, "
  + "                      y - 0.344 * u - 0.714 * v, "
  + "                      y + 1.77 * u, 1);\n"
  + "}\n";
```

and It seems simply draw a frame with rectangle shape

So I thought It would work on CardboardView too. But It dosen't draw properly in VRmode like this:

[image]

I checked it draws properly when I disable VRmode

This following code is the actual drawing code in my onDrawEye() method. I just simply adapt [SurfaceViewRenderer.java](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/app/webrtc/java/android/org/webrtc/SurfaceViewRenderer.java) code

```
// Fetch and render |pendingFrame|.
    final VideoRenderer.I420Frame frame;

    synchronized (frameLock) {
        if (pendingFrame == null) {
            return;
        }
        frame = pendingFrame;
        pendingFrame = null;
    }

    final long startTimeNs = System.nanoTime();
    final float[] texMatrix;

    synchronized (layoutLock) {
        final float[] rotatedSamplingMatrix = RendererCommon.rotateTextureMatrix(frame.samplingMatrix, frame.rotationDegree);
        final float[] layoutMatrix = RendererCommon.getLayoutMatrix(mirror, frameAspectRatio(), (float) layoutWidth / layoutHeight);
        texMatrix = RendererCommon.multiplyMatrices(rotatedSamplingMatrix, layoutMatrix);
    }

     GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (frame.yuvFrame) {
        // Make sure YUV textures are allocated.
        if (yuvTextures == null) {
            yuvTextures = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
                yuvTextures[i] = createTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            }
        }

        drawer.uploadYuvData(
                yuvTextures, frame.width, frame.height, frame.yuvStrides, frame.yuvPlanes);
        drawer.drawYuv(yuvTextures, texMatrix);
    } else {
        drawer.drawOes(frame.textureId, texMatrix);
    }

    VideoRenderer.renderFrameDone(frame);

    synchronized (statisticsLock) {
        if (framesRendered == 0) {
            firstFrameTimeNs = startTimeNs;
        }
        ++framesRendered;
        renderTimeNs += (System.nanoTime() - startTimeNs);
        if (framesRendered % 300 == 0) {
            logStatistics();
        }
    }
```

I'm still cannot figure out what is the reason. How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: It seems it draws only first(?) frame correctly then draws without textures like the above picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Using OpenGL tracer I found a solution. Actually It was simple.

Every time drawYuv() called in GlRectDrawer.java it prepares the shaders and set vertex attributes which are vertex and texture coordinates. When this is called in onDrawEye() in CardboardView then CardboardView does distortion correction that uses other shaders and vertex attributes.

For the next frame the vertex attributes to be set same as in drawYuv(). Original GlRectDrawer.java source doesn't set vertex data in every call So I just simply set vertex data again.

Comment: hey @kju can you please post some code, how you used SurfaceViewRenderer.java  with opengl

Comment: @Shishram I actually used VideoRendererGui.java for drawing. I uploaded [CardboardRenderer.java](https://gist.github.com/kjw0723/f052505a7a771b262fa1cd1b3e819d4e) class that is modified version for Google Cardboard. This is quite old version so you don't have to create separate ImageRenders.